# How to get this ajax to work in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to get this to work, but I really can't get where the problem is. This is code.
I try to render comment without refreshing page, after creating them.

**create.js.erb**

```
$('.post').append("<%= escape_javascript render(@comment) %>");
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post">
        <p><strong> <%= post.title %> </strong>, posted <%= post.created_at.to_date %> </p> <br />
        <%= post.content %> <br />

        <%= simple_form_for [post, post.comments.build], :remote => true do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :content %>
            <%= f.button :submit %>
        <% end %>


        <% post.comments.each_with_index do |comment, i| %>
            <p> <%=i + 1%>.<%= comment.content %></p>
        <% end %>

    </div>

<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %></p>
```

Comment: is there any comment partial is there? any error what would be the result in js console

Comment: I would have the javascript log to the console or make a popup alert when it's called just to confirm it is getting run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for firefox so you can debug your ajax and js code. I usually use it when adding ajax to my application to make sure there are not any errors.

Comment: @PrzemekMroczek accept the answer above if I helped resolved the issue.